Outlook Add-in: Failed to Open .docx File in MS Word from iFrame Due to URL Scheme Error
I'm developing an Outlook add-in where I need to open a .docx file stored on a cloud server directly in Microsoft Word, specifically in edit mode. The process involves the following steps:

I open an iframe within the Outlook add-in.
In the iframe, I select the .docx file stored on a cloud server.
After selecting the file, a dialog opens with a blank screen.

The issue arises with the following error in the console log of the new dialog:
Failed to load resource: Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)
The URL causing the issue is in the following format:
ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7Chttps://<Url of the document in cloud server>
It seems that the ms-word protocol is not being handled correctly, leading to the dialog opening blank.
What I've Tried:

Ensuring that the URL is correctly encoded.
Confirming that the file is accessible via a standard HTTP(S) URL.
Unfortunately, I cannot listen to any events when the dialog is opened, and I don't have access to the code inside the iframe—only to the original add-in.

Questions:

How can I correctly open the .docx file in MS Word from the iframe in edit mode?
Is there a way to bypass or handle the "Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)" error within an Outlook add-in?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
